# Data transformation

Tags: sql-server, migration, data-warehouse, etl

so, I'm facing this issue in storing my file in my database. I have an excel file that I need to load in database. The file looks like this:

The issue is that I need to store all this in columns: Date, Brand, KPI1, KPI2, KPI3, KPI4, KPI5. I have tried a lot and was unable to transform it anyhow. I even tried getting a raw file, but it happens so that I cant get that.

[image: 1st row contains dates and 1st column contains products and 5 KPI for that product]

Comment: I'll make a data warehouse out of it. It will be an on-going process.

Comment: So, I just updated the image of how my data looks. Can you please look at it again?

Comment: what steps are you taking to do the import?  SSIS, "Import Data" from SSMS, perhaps a bulk load app?

Comment: I'm using Pentahoo OR Altrex as the ETL tool.

Comment: The file has around 25 brands, and there are multiple such files I need to work around with.

Comment: Shoot I don't use those tools enough to give you a good answer.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to load the data to a staging table, adding an identity column to maintain the original order, then process the data row-by-row; that, or create a non-SQL process to build a standard file out of the CSV file (again, using row-by-row-processing). You might be able to do some sort of `UNPIVOT`, but I haven't worked with that personally.

Comment: Agreed with @RDFozz.  The Brand should be a column (BrandID or something like that) in the staging table.  This would make for much easier loading.

Comment: I dont get how assigning IDs would help. Can you please clarify your answer by giving some detail?

Comment: The earlier replies are suggesting that brand should a column and/or use an id so its tabular and can be queried reliably. Right now if you queried where column A =kpi 1 you will get many rows without knowing which product it relates to. You are relying upon the order of the rows to infer the relationship. It looks like you are using a report for ETL/integration which is a bad idea as it will be prone to fail. I reccomend trying again to get a more reliable export file format.

Comment: It happens so that this is the most raw form of this file. This data isn't something that can be extracted from some system directly. System outputs would have been heaven to work around with. Also, I do have a product dimension that I'll join with this. The only issue is how to re-format it so that it can be made in to a data warehouse.